# numpy bincount sequential slices of array

Tags: python, numpy, decision-tree

Given numpy row containing numbers from `range(n)`,
I want to apply the following transformation:

```
[1 0 1 2] --> [[0 1 0] [1 1 0] [1 2 0] [1 2 1]]
```

We just go through the input list and bincount all elements to the left of the current (including).

```
import numpy as np

n = 3
a = np.array([1, 0, 1, 2])
out = []
for i in range(a.shape[0]):
    out.append(np.bincount(a[:i+1], minlength=n))
out = np.array(out)
```

Is there any way to speed this up? I'm wondering if it's possible to get rid of that loop completely and use matrix magic only.

EDIT:
Thanks, lbragile, for mentioning list comprehensions. It's not what I meant. (I'm not sure if it's even significant asymptotically). I was thinking about some more complex things such as rewriting this based on how bincount operation works under the hood.

Comment: Can you explain the transformation a bit more? I'm not sure I understand it correctly.

Comment: I agree with Alexander, your explanation of the transformation is unclear and thus we cannot help you optimize if we don't know what is being optimized. Plus your code isn't running properly, unless you have append() as a defined function it should not take any arguments.

Comment: In any case, you can always optimize using list comprehension rather than your for-loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use cumsum like so:

```
idx = [1,0,1,2]
np.identity(np.max(idx)+1,int)[idx].cumsum(0)

# array([[0, 1, 0],
#        [1, 1, 0],
#        [1, 2, 0],
#        [1, 2, 1]])
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using list comprehension:**

```
fast_out = [np.bincount(a[:i+1], minlength=n) for i in range(a.shape[0])]
print(fast_out)
```

**Output:**

```
[array([0, 1, 0]), array([1, 1, 0]), array([1, 2, 0]), array([1, 2, 1])]
```

**To time the code use the following:**

```
import timeit

def timer(code_to_test):
    elapsed_time = timeit.timeit(code_to_test, number=100)/100
    print(elapsed_time)

your_code = """
import numpy as np

n = 3
a = np.array([1, 0, 1, 2])
out = []
for i in range(a.shape[0]):
    out.append(np.bincount(a[:i+1], minlength=n))
out = np.array(out)
"""

list_comp_code = """
import numpy as np

n = 3
a = np.array([1, 0, 1, 2])
fast_out = [np.bincount(a[:i+1], minlength=n) for i in range(a.shape[0])]
"""

timer(your_code) # 0.001330663086846471
timer(list_comp_code) # 1.4601880684494972e-05
```

So the list comprehension method is **over 91 times faster** when averaged over 100 trials.